# How can I adjust the scale-independent pixel (sp) settings in the emulator?

Tags: android, text, accessibility

I want to be using sp instead of dp for text in my application, in order to allow the user (according to the documentation) to scale the text for accessibility reasons.  I need to test my layouts against this, to make sure there aren't any visual problems, such as text getting cut off or hidden.  My problem is, I can't find any way to adjust this setting in the emulator or in any phone I have access to.  What I'm looking for is something that would let me adjust system text size preferences so that my 12sp text would appear bigger in the application.  How can I do this?

Comment: I believe there is no normal user-accessible preference. See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/is-there-a-user-accessible-font-size-preference. This is from 2010 but things haven't changed since then afaik.

Comment: If you want to restate that as an answer so I can mark resolved, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I believe there is no normal user-accessible preference. See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/is-there-a-user-accessible-font-size-preference) on the Android stackexchange. This is from 2010 but things haven't changed since then afaik.</strike>

Ok, this answer was completely false. There are two options in Android 4 (ICS) to change the text size:

- `Settings -> Display -> Font size`
  *This allows to set a general text size (small, medium, large, ..)*
- `Settings -> Accessibility -> Large Text`
  *Upscales all text entries*

They both modify the same setting though, so when you enable `Large text` under accessibility, it changes the font size to huge.

Comment: Because there is no way to properly test this, I have decided NOT to use sp, and would advise others to do the same, with exceptions made on a case-by-case basis, testing by manually incrementing the text size to check wrapping and cutoff.

Comment: @MicahHainline Just went over the [typography section](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) in the design guide and they mentioned this preference again. So I decided to check all settings through. Turns out this answer was false, there are settings now. I'm sorry.